# English Philology vs English studies difference in meaning and connotations for Natives?

Tags: meaning, philology

In Poland, English University major is called "English Philology" (pol. Filologia Angielska), and this is how it is usually translated and communicated. By the Poles. 
When you google English philology, oddly enough, only sites of Polish Universities come up. After doing some old classic research I decided to entitle myself as an English Studies graduate, as it maybe says more about the scope. But I decided to maybe clash my understanding of the term with yours.

For me, English Philology does not carry the same meaning in English as it does in Polish, this is why I strive to find a more fitting term.

P.S To clarify: We're obviously not talking about ESL courses, but a fully-scoped education of the language arts, but boosted with linguistics (syntax, phonetics, morphology, phonology), the history of the language itself and the countries using it, and obviously English and American lit.

Your input is much appreciated <3.

Comment: Are you searching from Poland? I get a list of different sites from different countries (Germany, Finland and Poland).

Comment: [English has its philologists of renown](https://www.tolkienestate.com/en/learning/thoughts-and-studies/tolkien-and-philology.html), a field not to be dismissed as extinct or anti-American.

Answer (score 1):

In the American system education system, there is no such thing as a study of English philology. Surely there is a concept of philology which includes study of both literature and composition, language history, practical language study, and theoretical linguistics, but the academic faculties where teaching of those occur don't put them all together.

- There is *linguistics* which teaches the abstract science of languages in general.
- There are language programs which teach how to speak particular *foreign* languages to native English speakers (or possibly English as a foreign language to non-native speakers). Sometimes linguistics and languages are kept together in the same department (a professor of phonology may also happen to be an expert on Hindi and teach that also). But often linguistics and specific languages are in different departments.
- There are '*studies*' programs. This implies an area concentration for native speakers. For example, an 'American studies' program, it is most likely entirely American history, literature and culture together. These classes may be taught in different departments. I don't think there's anything like an 'English studies' program in the US; it is just called 'English'.

This division of studies is from the American system; it may well be different in the education systems of other primarily English speaking countries.

But the term 'X philology', for either English or for foreign languages X is not used .

So to translate or give an impression of the degree, you would say **English language and literature** or **English literature and history** or whatever subjects are included. It is a bit old-fashioned but one *could* say 'English letters', but that is as vague as 'English philology' would be nowadays.

As an aside, I'd be surprised if in Polish universities if there were a single faculty that teaches Polish language and Polish literature *to* native Poles.

Comment: There is actually, if I understand you correctly. Yet again, in PL it is called "Polish philology"... I think it is a matter of convention. It is like "English" major you mention, just ... well, Polish.  [btw, I am aware of 'the English major', just been wondering how to differentiate between the two, since I am clearly still not a Native].

Comment: @Patpat The only place *philology* remains a current term in AmE is in classical philology, i.e. the study of the literary patrimony of classical civilization, i.e. the Latin and ancient Greek of high antiquity. Even then, the university department is usually called the department of *classics* or *classical studies*, with classical philology being one program of study within it. For other cultures, and for modern languages, there is as Mitch notes a specialization into linguistics, language and literature, and area or cultural studies.

Comment: @Patpat In English, in the US, You just don't say 'English Philology'. It isn't used for whatever you mean by it. I think people will understand it as a calque from most any non-English European language, but it isn't used for the corresponding situation in the US. You say either 'English Literature' or 'English Language' or 'American Studies' (for history and culture) in the US. For translating the Polish label for the thing _in Poland_, I think it is most often translated as 'English Language and Literature'.

Comment: Perhaps you mean it's unused by people in America who lack the vocabulary of Academe. I don't know that it matters that they are ignorant of [English philology](https://www.tolkienestate.com/en/learning/thoughts-and-studies/tolkien-and-philology.html). Harvard (yes, that one) for example has [a couple philology profs](https://linguistics.fas.harvard.edu/people/faculty). I wonder what us unejukit Amerikids are sposed to call them in Merikin, maybe lingodoofers?

Comment: American studies programs study America, not American.

Comment: @tchrist Note that what Tolkien was trained in would not nowadays be called comparative philology, but comparative (and/or historical) _linguistics_. Philology deals specifically with analysis of written records, deciphering of manuscripts/sources, and language use as evidenced from these sources. Comparative linguistics, on the other hand, deals less with the use of languages and more with their structure and internal relatednesses. Where philology is exclusively _descriptive_, comparatively linguistics is primarily _reconstructive_.

Comment: (That’s not to say that Tolkien did not carry out a lot of actual English philology, such as analysing the vocabulary of Old English dialects based on their extant records. He absolutely did. But his degree was, I believe, in something which would nowadays belong in the department of linguistics rather than in philology.)

Comment: @Mitch, Yes, there is Polish philology in Poland and it is only because of their language Council the joke remains, "you shouldn't study what you want for your art, to be about Polish philology".  On the other hand (of course), study in depth has advantages.